# IONIC Typescript - To delete item from firebase list

Tags: typescript, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

I have firebase (realtime database) simple structure like this:
As the key value will be "unit no" .

[image]

My output screen as below ：
example , when search unit no "1-2" , able to list out the item filter by unit no .

when try to click "confirm recipient " to specific item , I want the remove the only record from firebase .

here is the problem facing :

**1) undefine value for "item.unitno" anf "item.trakno"**
**2) TypeError: Cannot read property 'unitno' of undefined**

[image]
[image]

html

```
   <ion-row *ngFor="let item of result; let idx = index" class="text-content">
            <ion-col class="table-cell" size="3">{{item.unitno}}</ion-col>
            <ion-col class="table-cell" size="3">{{item.trackno}}</ion-col>
            <ion-col class="table-cell" size="3">{{item.mydate | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd'}}</ion-col>
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" (click)="receiveparcel(item)" size="3">Confirm by recipient</button>
```

TS

```
 async receiveparcel(item) {  
       
                var db = firebase.database().ref('post/');
                var query = firebase.database().ref('post/').orderByKey();

                query.once("value").then(function(snapshot) {

                  snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
                    var pkey = childSnapshot.key; 
                    var chval = childSnapshot.val();
            
                    //check if remove this child
                    
                     if(chval.unitno == item.unitno && chval.trackno == item.trackno){
                      console.log(item.unitno);
                      console.log(item.trackno);

                      console.log(pkey);
                      console.log(chval);
                     

                      db.child("post/" +pkey).remove();
                 
                       return true;
                    }
                  });
                });
              }
```

Latest :

sorry my mistake .forgot to save the html .now manage to resolve the type error however .the particular firebase record still not deleted even clicked the "receiveparcel" function.

[image]

**After amend:**
result after amended . no error found however the record still not able to remove ?

[image]

Comment: Inside `receiveparcel` function, try logging `item` and share what the output is?

Comment: Hi sir , can check my update under "latest" ? the type error due to html not save .sorry for mistake. however the record not able to remove yet

```   
console.log(item.unitno);  => 1-2
console.log(item.trackno);  =>1rurur58588
```

Comment: There were some issue with promises. Try copying code from my answer and running it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code looks correct expect you are using `.remove()` which returns a promise without `await` in a `forEach` loop. You cannot use `await` in a for each loop I'd recommend adding those delete operations into an object and then using the `update` method as shown:

```ts
async receiveparcel(item) {  
  var db = firebase.database().ref('post/');
  var query = firebase.database().ref('post/').orderByKey();

  const snapshot = await query.once("value")
  const updateObj = {}

  snapshot.forEach(function (childSnapshot) {
    var pkey = childSnapshot.key; 
    var chval = childSnapshot.val();
            
    //check if remove this child
    if(chval.unitno == item.unitno && chval.trackno == item.trackno) {
      console.log(item.unitno, item.trackno);
      console.log("pkey:", pkey, "& chval:", chval);
                     
      updateObj[pkey] = null
      // don't return from within forEach loop
    }
  });

  await db.update(updateObj)
  return true
}
```

Comment: Hi Sir , can pls check my result "after amend" . the record still not deleted.. –

Comment: @brook18 can you please `console.log(updateObj)` before `await db.update(updateObj)` and share the output?

Comment: { post/-MfkicdEtDyjLtRlAt9r: null }

Comment: @brook18 oh right. Can you try `updateObj[pkey] = null`? Remove the `/posts` as in updated answer.

Comment: @brook18 great. If you liked my answer you can also upvote it :)